# Dynamics CRM - creating a dynamic list of products, each with a cost field

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm new to customizing dynamics CRM, and I need to implement a custom form with a list that lets you add and remove "fruits" for a fruit store. To better illustrate what I need, I've attached a photo [image: custom field control in form]

I have "x" number of fruit types in a fruit store. The list of fruits can be managed and changed via the store owner. I want to be able to click add, choose a fruit from a list of fruits, then specify an amount, and have it update a total.

I want this in a form for an entity like Opportunity. Where do I begin with this level of customisation?

Does it involve creating a custom silver light control? Or is there something out of the box?

Comment: Which version are you working 4.0 or 2011? Online or On-Premise?

Answer (score 2):

By default you don't have anything to accomplish that. To extend user interface of CRM you have recurring to WebResource, there is two types of WebResources that you can explore html or Silverlight. For me the best option is Silverlight.

You have some generic examples here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-create-a-silverlight-web-resource-that-interacts-with-crm-2011-forms.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328358.aspx

You have some examples of grids:

- http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2013/01/crm-2011-lookup-functionality-in.html

If you need interact with CRM Database:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309558.aspx
- http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crminogic/archive/2011/07/27/json-and-silverlight-with-odataservice-in-crm-2011.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the technology used would be editable grids, javascript. Silverlight is dead.